# capDlgVideoSource problems with multiple webcams

Tags: webcam, vfw

I have two different webcams connected to my PC, but I have problems choosing them when running the following code. I included all the initialization routine and the last line with capDlgVideoSource call is causing only the one webcam's videosource dialog to appear instead of a list where I can choose between them. OS is WinXP SP3

```
//Create invisible window to hold the capture window.
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, _T("webcampcapwindow"), _T(""), 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
if( !hwnd ) 
    throw FatalException( _T("main Capture window create failed"), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__ );

//Create capture window.
capHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindow(_T("webcampcapwindowchild"), WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 1, 1, hwnd, 1);
if( !capHwnd ) 
    throw FatalException( _T("secondary Capture window create failed"), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__ );

CAPDRIVERCAPS caps;
if(capDriverConnect(capHwnd, 0)) {
    connectedtoWc = true;
    break;
}

if ( !connectedtoWc )
    throw FatalException( _T("Could not connect to capture driver."), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__ );

//Attach our callback to the capture window.
if( !capSetCallbackOnVideoStream(capHwnd, videoCallback))
    throw FatalException( _T("Unable to Attach our callback to the capture window."), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__ );

//Make sure we can access this object from the callback.
if(!capSetUserData(capHwnd, this))
    throw FatalException( _T("Could not associate user data with capture."), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__ );

//Check everything's initialised.
caps.fCaptureInitialized = false;
if( !capDriverGetCaps(capHwnd, &caps, sizeof(CAPDRIVERCAPS)))
    throw FatalException( _T("Unable to get driver caps"), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__ );

if(!caps.fCaptureInitialized)
    throw FatalException( _T("Unable to initialize capture driver"), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__ );

if (caps.fHasDlgVideoSource)
    capDlgVideoSource(capHwnd);
```

What do I change so I can get to select the webcam in video source dialog? Currently it shows the second webcam properties.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear from your question, and I'm no expert, but it would appear you're using VfW, which many camera drivers don't support anymore.

Support is built in using a WDM backwards compatibility driver, which doesn't seem to work very well.  The only solution I've seen to this problem is to perform some registry gymnastics (set `DevicePath` in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaResources\msvideo\MSVideo.VFWWDM` to the desired device), but this is a bit over my head - I'm a hardware guy.